# Actors and dask-workers

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

```
client = Client('127.0.0.1:8786',direct_to_workers=True)
future1 = client.submit(Counter, workers= 'ninja',actor=True)   
counter1 = future1.result()                    
print(counter1)
```

All is well but what if the client gets restarted? How do I get the 
actor back from the worker called ninja?

Answer (score 1):

There is no user-facing way to do this as of 2019-03-06

I recommend raising a feature request issue